# G++ compiler doesn't show any output

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, g++

I'm a newbie and I'm stuck with the basic stuff. A friend of mine showed me Geany and Ubuntu to code C++ and I loved them, so I downloaded Ubuntu an hour ago. I've got the IDE but when I try to compile, it just doesn't show any ouput. I'm trying to run the simplest C++ programme:

```
include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```

When I use

```
g++ p.cpp
```

it just show nothing as an output.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Cv49U

Answer (score 2):

In *nix, the convention is that "no command line output" means that the command worked as instructed.

In this case, your command

```
g++ p.cpp
```

should have produced an executable file with the default name `a.out` which you can run from the terminal using `./a.out`

Comment: chmod +x is needed though.

Comment: @Pilot6 that's not the case in my experience - `gcc` / `g++` will apply executable permissions to executables that it produces

Comment: Really? I did not know that and always did chmod. But it is easy to test.

Comment: Just tested. It really does.